# INSERT into two tables in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, transactions, inner-join, commit

I have two table which is **STAFF** and **LOGIN**

**STAFF**

```
staffId    - Number
staffName  - Text
staffEmail - Text
```

**LOGIN**

```
staffName  - Text
staffPwd   - Text
```

My question is, how to execute a query to insert "Name" into `STAFF.staffName` and `LOGIN.staffName`

Since i am new to access, can anyone help me out? Any suggestions? Can i use inner join? If so, how?

Note: I am using VB.NET and Access 2010. So the data from the textbox `staffName.Text` should be inserted into two table (LOGIN & STAFF)

So it will be something like this:

```
Dim mysql As String = "INSERT INTO STAFF VALUES ('" & txt_id.Text & "', '" & txt_name.Text & "', '" & txt_username.Text & "', '" & txt_username.Text & "', '" & txt_email.Text & "')"
```

But this is for table **STAFF** without inserting into **LOGIN**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `insert` data into two tables then you need two separate `insert` statements.

For `STAFF` table

```
INSERT INTO STAFF(staffId,staffName,staffEmail) VALUES (..
```

For `LOGIN` table

```
INSERT INTO LOGIN(staffName,staffPwd) VALUES (..
```

As a side note you should refer `staffId` in `LOGIN` table instead of `staffName`. Two `staff's` can have same name

Comment: can i make it into one query?

Comment: @AthirahHazira - Not possible in any `SQL`  standard

Comment: even using transactions like in sql server? or using inner join maybe?

Comment: `INNER JOIN` is used to **Join** two tables and retrieve data from joined tables not to insert data into two tables

Comment: Okay. my bad but what about transactions? I've used transactions in sql server before? Example:

`BEGIN TRANSACTION
   
   INSERT INTO [MRS].[dbo].[USER]
   (EmployeeId, UserName, UserDept, UserGrade, UserEmail, UserType, SuperiorId)
   VALUES
   ('$strEmployeeId', '$strUserName', '$strUserDept', '$strUserGrade', '$strUserEmail', '$strUserType', '$strSuperiorId')
   
   INSERT INTO [MRS].[dbo].[LOGIN]
   (EmployeeId, UserType, Password)
   VALUES
   ('$strEmployeeId', '$strUserType', '$strUserPwd')
   
   COMMIT`

Comment: @AthirahHazira - yeah, it will work. But still you have two separate insert's